# Is there a way to get python to output to the shell and simultaneously output to str in a variable?

Tags: python, stdout, sys

The only ways I can find in python that redirects the console output to string in a variable also seem to turn off the functionality of displaying the output to the console in a live manner similar to how python would output the code normally.

I currently am changing the sys.stdout but again, this is either one or the other it seems.

If I redefine it, I get the perfect performance for distant error checking, as I am able to save the output variable to a cloud based spreadsheet in the event of exception handling, which sends me notifications anywhere that I am.

However, redefining it means I don't get to come and locally check on the output of the program while it is "running smoothly"

EDIT: some of your answers have helped me refine my question. Here is a fresh re wording:

What is the best way to concisely store and record outputs with a single variable as the elements are printed to the console without overwriting sys.stdout?

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
new_stdout = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = new_stdout

def update_error_log_ss(traceback_, summary, output = ""):
    print("Connecting to Smart Sheet to Update Error Log")
    token = 'token'
    error_log_sheetid = 00000000
    ss_client = ss.Smartsheet(token)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    sheet = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(error_log_sheetid)
    colid = []
    for col in sheet.columns:
        colid.append(col.id)
        print(str(col.id) + " - " + col.title)
    totalcols = len(colid)
    row_add = ss.models.Row()
    row_add.to_top = True
    row_add.cells.append({
        'column_id': colid[0],
        'value': str(now)
    })
    row_add.cells.append({
        'column_id': colid[1],
        'value': summary
    })
    row_add.cells.append({
        'column_id': colid[2],
        'value': traceback_
    })
    row_add.cells.append({
        'column_id': colid[3],
        'value': output
    })
    response = ss_client.Sheets.add_rows(
        error_log_sheetid,
        [row_add]
    )

    return

except Exception:
        if debug_ == False:
synch.update_error_log_ss(traceback.format_exc(),'initialization failure',new_stdout.getvalue())
main_()
        else:
            synch.update_error_log_ss(traceback.format_exc(),'initialization failure')
        main_()
```

The only issue I have with the above solution is that in order for  new_stdout.getvalue() to get defined, sys.stdout has to be overwritten

Comment: You can then just print the variable to display its contents.

Comment: How are you calling/running python?

Comment: In the scenario where I need this, I am simply calling python through a batch file. Ideally it runs 24/7. Sometimes I would like to be able to check up on the command window and watch the output, but in the event of an error, I would also like for the output be sent to cloud based spreadsheet where I get a nicely formatted email with context - hence the need for the keeping the output as a variable as well as regularly outputting everything.

Comment: You might be able to use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) here but it is not clear to me what *"save the output variable to a cloud based spreadsheet"* means...

Comment: edited in the output to smartsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`print` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> The file argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method

So you can just create one for your needs and assign it to `sys.stdout` which is the default `file` argument for `print`:

```py
import io
import sys

class my_stdout:
    def __init__(self):
        self.real_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.new_stdout = io.StringIO()

    def write(self, s):
        self.real_stdout.write(s)
        self.new_stdout.write(s)

    def getvalue(self):
        return self.new_stdout.getvalue()

new_stdout = my_stdout()
sys.stdout = new_stdout
print("Original: Hello world!")
# for debug:
sys.stdout = new_stdout.real_stdout
print("From stringio:", new_stdout.getvalue())
```

Output:

```
Original: Hello world!
From stringio: Original: Hello world!
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Its a sys.stdout overwrite that doesn't lack the original functionality, just adds to it. Thank you

Comment: You are very welcome! Thank *you* for the question. It was a nice experiment and I enjoyed reaching this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
def get(x):
    print(x)
    return x

myvar = get('myvalue')

print(myvar)
```

Output:

```
myvalue
myvalue
```

So basically just write your own function to print the value and return it to the variable.

Comment: So the program I am trying to achieve this with has ~1800 lines, the built in print function gets called around 100 times roughly through the life cycle of the program. this solution would require going through and adding a new line that references this user defined function "get" everywhere I currently have a print function. Am I correct?

Comment: No you're wrong. The function needs to be defined once only on top of your file. Then call it as much as you want. You could simply do a replace of print by get in your script and that's it. By replace I mean ctrl+r.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me here. I understand the solution you are proposing. The implementation is only this simple though if I am okay with 100 different variables for every instance I want to print something. I am looking for a concise way to store one variable that captures 'print history' through the entirety of the program without redefining sys.stdout your answers have helped me refine my question a bit